# Convert this Visualforce - Javascript to Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have requirement to transform this code into lightning. I can see that sforce.connection.query is not working in lightning. I am new into lightning development and not sure what is the **best approach with minimal coding**. Should I go to aura component with VF pages.  This is working in classic and VF page is  embedeed on page layout and execute once contract is loaded. Should i  keep the VF page with extension controller? I will appreciate if sample code is given. Thanks.

```
<apex:page standardController="contract" tabStyle="Contract" >
<script src="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SecurePage(){
    var value = '';


    if (value == null)
    {
        var theAccountName = "";
        var theQuery = "SELECT name FROM Account where Id='{!Contract.Account}'";
        var qr = sforce.connection.query(theQuery);
        var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(qr);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            var account = it.next();
            theAccountName = account.Name;
        }

        var theMessage = "Access to this document is restricted.  Do not click OK to proceed unless you are authorized to view this object.  Note that this access will be recorded.";
        if (confirm(theMessage ) == true)
        {
            var newCAT = new sforce.SObject("ContractAccessTracker__c");
            newCAT.username__c = "{!$User.Username}";
            newCAT.Name = "{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}";
            newCAT.ContractRecordType__c = "{!Contract.RecordType.Name}";
            newCAT.ContractNumber__c = "{!Contract.ContractNumber}";
            newCAT.AccountName__c = theAccountName;
            newCAT.Status__c = "{!Contract.Status}";
            result = sforce.connection.create([newCAT]);
            setCookie('esrica-{!Contract.Id}', 'some value set from external cookie', 1);
        }
        else
        {
        top.location = "/home/home.jsp";
        }
    }
}
if ('{!$Profile.Name}' != 'Lightning Legal')
{
    window.onload=SecurePage();
}
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create a controller for your Lightning Component with AuraEnabled https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm

Once you have that controller, convert the SOQL in your JS to Apex. Return the data as an Object or as a List (depending on your preference). You will need to parse the returned data in your Lightning Component Helper class. A Lightning bundle has a controller.js and a helper.js the controller will route "traffic" or logical operations to the helper class which does the heavy lifting. Once you have parsed your response data, display it on your Lightning component using any number of the out of the box components provided. See the Aura section here... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components

If you are feeling adventurous, learn Lightning Web Components... as a VFP developer, you will like some of the hook-ins that are provided for "free" to server-side data.

Comment: if I create a Lightning component, can I drag the component into the page and load/execute before accessing the contract page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly Smurfet but you do have fine grained control of the UI with Lightning Components. If you are trying to control when the record page loads, that is not possible. The Lightning component would be added to the Lightning Layout of your record page and you could have it load first if you use tabs.